# Remote Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, desktop-computer, multiple-computers

Our family uses only laptops and smartphones for our current computing needs. I am an amateur photographer, and need to store large amounts of data on a hard drive. While I could get external hard drives and store my pictures on that, I would like to have them immediately available to all of our computers if possible. My ideal situation would be some sort of remote hard drive which is WiFi connected and able to be accessed remotely from our laptops to avoid having to store large amounts of data on the hard drive of the laptops. I’ve thought about cloud storage, which is an option as well, but would love to know if a hard drive is an option. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Most routers allow you to connect a USB external drive to it, allowing anyone access to the drive, that is connected to your intranet network.  Have you tried that?  You can also connect an HDD to a single machine, then create a network location, and allow other devices.  Have you tried either of these solutions?  There are also external HDDs on the market that connect directly to your network.  Product recommendations are out of scope.  Please do not ask us to recommend a specific product.

Answer (score 1):

Seagate makes a [Personal Cloud Home Media Storage Device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PZZZMQC) that sounds like what you're looking for: it's a home-based hard drive that can be accessed over Wi-Fi locally, and/or remotely if you have that function set up on your home router.